# How do I print something after pattern match in awk script?

Tags: awk

My Input File Data

```
 public class XXX
{
   private String XX ="";

   @Override
   public void toString(){
   }
}
```

> awk **/public void toString/{print nitin}**

**output like this**

```
public class XXX{

   private String XX ="";

   @Override
   nitin
   public void toString(){
   }
}
```

**But I want**

```
public class XXX{

   private String XX ="";

   nitin
   @Override
   public void toString(){
   }
}
```

**In pattern match if i use @override then it will edit other methods also which @override.**

Please suggest How I can achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me given your input file and desired output:

```
/@Override/ {
  override = 1;
  override_string = $0; # @Override might be indented at various levels
  next;
}

override && ! /public void toString/ {
  print override_string;
  print $0;
  override = 0;
  next;
}

override && /public void toString/ {
  # Get indent
  match($0, /^\s*/, matches);
  indent = matches[0];

  printf("%s%s\n", indent, "nitin");
  print override_string;
  print $0;

  override = 0;
  next;
}

{
  print;
}
```

Here is an alternative solution using [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable.html#Getline_002fVariable):

```
/@Override/ {
  getline nextline;
  if(nextline ~ /public void toString[(]/) {
    match($0, /^\s*/, matches); # get indent
    indent = matches[0];
    printf("%s%s\n", indent, "nitin");
    print $0;
    print nextline;
    next;
  } else {
    print $0;
    print nextline;
    next;
  }
}

{
  print;
}
```